# Alter and set a id attribute for a field in drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

Can anyone help me how to alter a field attribute  in drupal 7. Let say i have created a field name hello_test with label as hello.Now I need to alter the label and set a attribute for the filed in template.php file in my theme.Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to implement [template_preprocess_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) in your theme's template.php

Also helpful to you will be the drupal.org documentation on [Overriding Themable Output](http://drupal.org/node/173880).